# pass byte[] to stimulsoft using variable to display on image

Tags: c#, wpf, stimulsoft

I want to pass my logo `byte array` that fetched from **sql database**(varbinary) to my stimulsoft report using variable and show in Image component on header.

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
byte[] ImageByteArray = ReadLogoFromSqlDataBase();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImageByteArray);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

StiReport rpt = new StiReport();
rpt.ReportFile = "rpt1.mrt";
rpt.Dictionary.Variables.Add("Logo", image);
rpt.Design(); or rpt.Print();
```